# Installing auto-py-to-exe module for Python 3.7 returns an error on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.7, auto-py-to-exe

I am trying to install the auto-py-to-exe module using the following command:

`pip install auto-py-to-exe`

but returns the following error:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\ea_e90434\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\ea_e90434\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Us
ers\EA_E90~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i1b74fjx\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -- '
setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (8 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0648D210>: Fail
ed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0648D270>: Fail
ed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0648D350>: Fail
ed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0648D3F0>: Fail
ed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0648D470>: Fail
ed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\ea_e90434\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\ea_e90434\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-
installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\EA_E90~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i1b74fjx\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.org --trust
ed-host files.pythonhosted.org -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read in the error it seems like a networking issue to me.
Can you please try a simple ping from your command prompt to be sure that it is working correctly?
`ping 8.8.8.8`

Maybe you have an Antivirus / Firewall that needs to be - just temporarily for troubleshooting purpouse - disabled?

If all the above is fine please try the same command you used to install the module from a command window that was opened with administrator rights (right click on "command prompt" and then on "Execute as Administrator").

If this fails you can also install the module cloning it from the github repo using the following commands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe.git
$ cd auto-py-to-exe
$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: connection down??
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Timeout for this request.
Timeout for this request.
Timeout for this request.
Timeout for this request.